# MVC Action attribute testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib

I have an MVC3 application with the below action.

```
public class FooController : ApplicationController
{
  [My(baz: true)]
  public void Index()
  {
    return view("blah");
  }
}
```

I can write a test to verify that Index is decorated with MyAttribute using MVCContrib's TestHelper in this fashion.

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooControllerTest
{
  [Test]
  public void ShouldHaveMyAttribute()
  {
    var fooController = new FooController();
    fooController.Allows(x => x.Index(), new List<Type>{typeof(MyAttribute)});
  }
}
```

Question - How can this test be changed to test that the MyAttribute decoration includes the property 'baz' to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify the attribute in your unit tests, you'll need to use reflection to inspect your controller methods as follows.

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooController Tests 
{
    [Test]
    public void Verify_Index_Is_Decorated_With_My_Attribute() {
        var controller = new FooController ();
        var type = controller.GetType();
        var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("Index");
        var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), true);
        Assert.IsTrue(attributes.Any(), "MyAttribute found on Index");
        Assert.IsTrue(((MyAttribute)attr[0]).baz);
    }
}
```

this may help you

Comment: Yes, reflection is an option definitely, but I was looking for something simpler than this. Just for testing the parameter, my two liner tests would need to grow.

Comment: oh i see now you are using MVCContrib's Test Helpers, Not sure if there is any other option available there to check your condition.